# Use ES6 features and target ES5 without providing polyfills starting with a project that only has npm?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a simple TypeScript project that only has `npm` thus far, no other build tools. No `webpack` or `babel` yet.

What is the easiest good way to be able to use `ES6` features and target `ES5` without having to think about providing polyfills?

My impression is that `babel` and/or `webpack` might be suitable tools for this, but most guides I have found assume that one already uses `webpack` and `some front-end framework`. I haven't figured out what would be a good solution starting from a `vanilla TypeScript project` like I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tsconfig.json set target:"es5" and lib: ["es6"].

Typescript includes es6/es7 features and will transpile everything for you if you configure your tsconfig.json correctly

Comment: You're right! I remember I tried that sometimes and encountered the problem that TypeScript expected a polyfill for the String.prototype.pad method. But in the current project I don't use any ES6 properties, only language features. I don't remember exactly, but I think the TypeScript compiler can compile those down to ES5.